# How do you setup Microsoft OpenIdConnect?

Tags: authentication, configuration, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I spent a bunch of time trying to get this setup and never seems to progress to the point of success. I haven't found any examples that seem to put the latest configuration together and work.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true
});

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions()
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "Microsoft Signin",
    SignInScheme = "Cookies",
    Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0",
    ResponseType = "id_token",
    ClientId =    "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    ClientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    SaveTokens = true
});
```

I setup a Microsoft app creating a application id and secret code. Then I set the RedirectUrls to be http://localhost:12343/signin-microsoft which was the current location of my application. When I try to authenticate I receive this error.

```
We're unable to complete your request
Microsoft account is experiencing technical problems. Please try again later.
```

And in there is another error embedded in the URL address.

```
The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The 
expected value is 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf' or a URL which 
matches the redirect URI registered for this client application.
```

I have tried every variation that I can think up but nothing seems to work. I have also tried these things with the code hosted online just in case the server taking care of the authentication can't find the localhost but still no luck.

I have now changed the microsoft application RedirectUrls to a value of

http://localhost:10223/signin-oidc

When I authenticate it now sends me back to this location but I get a 500 error.

Comment: Did you look at this ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins they seems to have step by step tutorial ...

Comment: Is this different than OpenIdConnect? Seems like just authentication.

Comment: when you have a user logged in using the middleware, you should be able to iterate through and see the claims MSFT has passed through provided permission was granted by the user.

Comment: @Muqeet Khan. How would I go about iteration of claims?

Comment: you have to enable ssl for your site

Answer (score 0):

You could use Fiddler to grab the request , compare the value of `redirect_uri`  and the one config in application registration portal .

In addition , you could look into [this code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore-v2) which integrating Azure AD (v2.0 endpoint) into an ASP.NET Core web app . That code sample uses the ASP.Net Core OpenID Connect middleware , and enable sign-in users with Microsoft Accounts and accounts from multiple Azure Active Directory tenants .

Any problem during making above code sample work , please feel free to let me know .

Comment: The project in you linked is not using aspnetcore which is what I was trying to setup. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect

Comment: @jwize ,have you checked the project , it's a .net core project and use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect v1.0.0

Comment: Did you look at the link you posted? I looked in the project again and did a search for AspNetCore with no results found so it seems rather odd..

Comment: Please check [code part](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore-v2/blob/master/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/Startup.cs) ,it is a asp.net core app host on IIS , what is your scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I was following examples that were using

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication
```

There are extensions that set up the options that sort out most of the missing pieces.

```
var googleOptions = new GoogleOptions() { ... }
var facebookOptions = new FacebookOptions() { ... }
var twitterOptions = new TwitterOptions() { ... }
var options = new MicrosoftAccountOptions() { ... }

app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOptions);
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
app.UseTwitterAuthentication(twitterOptions);
app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(options);
```

Here is what the Micrsoft implementation looks like without the secret retrieval code included.

```
var options = new MicrosoftAccountOptions() 
{
    ClientId = "xxxxxx", 
    ClientSecret = "xxxxxxx",
};
app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(options);
```

The nuget OpenIdConnect extension packages are needed:

Micrsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect

Micrsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook

Micrsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google

Micrsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount

Micrsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter